# strange solr query with double quotes

Tags: solr, lucene

My fields defined as

```
<fieldType name="text_name" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="16"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Then I test query in solr admin

query with quotes, **the second query not work**

```
Input: q : real_name:"单"
Output:  {"id": 1,  "real_name": "单鑫鑫"}

Input: q : real_name:"单鑫"
Output:  {}

Input: q : real_name:"单鑫鑫"
Output:  {"id": 1,  "real_name": "单鑫鑫"}
```

query without quotes, **the second query works**

```
Input: q : real_name:单
Output:  {"id": 1,  "real_name": "单鑫鑫"}

Input: q : real_name:单鑫
Output:  {"id": 1,  "real_name": "单鑫鑫"}

Input: q : real_name:单鑫鑫
Output:  {"id": 1,  "real_name": "单鑫鑫"}
```

So, what extractly does double quotes mean ????

Answer (score -1):

Double quotes are for phrases. In Lucene searches work as follows,

```
field1:foo

field2:"foo bar"

field3:foo bar
```

Searches on field1 and field2 will work as expected whereas field3 will most likely error because it see the "bar" as separate from your search.

More reading here [Apache Lucene - Query Parser Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html)

Comment: I have read it. But I cannot found anything helpful. I have only one word for search. not many sepearated by space